# icon files to specify in plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Which/How many icon files are necessary to be included and specified in plist ?

I am getting error " Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found..." in Application Loader..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icon file 512 X 512 pixels is **not enough**. Infact in your plist you need to add 57 X 57 pixels icon which is in PNG Format

If you are developing iPhone app then the iPhone app icon should be **57 X 57** pixels exact and one high resolution icon which is **512 X 512** pixels.

You need to add the 57 X 57 pixel icon as your app icon in your project's plist.

So I think error suggests that you have not added your application icon (57 X 57 pixels.

This icons need to be in **PNG** format.

It may be the case that you might have added the icon name is your project's plist but you may not have referenced or added the icon to your app's resources or bundle.

**Note**:  512 X 512 pixels icon is not required to be included in Project bundle.

It needs to be similar to your application icon.

It is to be added to iTunes Page for your app when you submit your app on iTunes.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 5):

Here is the document you need.

QA1686

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Make sure the icon file is added to your project and matches the entry in your plist file.  See above document for details.

Comment: Actually I did see the link...So out of all the icons that Apple has listed what all are necessary...I only have one 512 x 512 icon..Is that enough ?

Answer (score 0):

As much you need in your project except application icon and splash screen :)

Comment: I am getting error " Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found..." in Application Loader..

Comment: OK :Read the similar post.                      http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13944-icon-help.html

Comment: this one may be more useful                                                   http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=9645600